# vba lookup value from other workbook and copy corresponding values?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks.

Workbook A

```
Item number     Item description     Supplier name        
1234            x                    c
123             y                    r
1111            b                    e
```

Workbook B:

```
1234      
123
1111
```

When the user types or pastes in an item number in workbook B, the item description and supplier name should be pulled through from workbook A.

This works. But sometimes its a bit temperamental. Sometimes the code works, but then as the user makes changes to the workbook, like when they delete a row in workbook B, this will stop the code from executing for the next time the user types in an item number.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Message
On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False        

'Insert Depot Memo Data for user
 Dim oCell As Range, targetCell As Range
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo Message
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column B has changed
        If Not GetWb("Depot Memo", ws2) Then Exit Sub

        With ws2
            For Each targetCell In Target
                Set oCell = .Range("J1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp)).Find(What:=targetCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not oCell Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False                                                                        
                    'Set Format of cell
                    targetCell.ClearFormats
                    targetCell.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    targetCell.Font.Size = "10"
                    targetCell.Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
                    targetCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    targetCell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    targetCell.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    targetCell.Borders.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)
                    targetCell.Borders.Weight = xlThin                                                                        
                    targetCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -2)
                    targetCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = oCell.Offset(0, -7)

                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If                       

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True                                
Exit Sub        

Message:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Exit Sub

End Sub

'=================================================================

Function GetWb(wbNameLike As String, WS As Worksheet) As Boolean
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    For Each Wb In Workbooks
        If Wb.Name Like "*" & wbNameLike & "*" Then '<-- check if workbook name contains "Depot Memo"
            Set WS = Wb.Worksheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    GetWb = Not WS Is Nothing
End Function
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: A simple vlookup will retrieve column data from a closed workbook and that is all you require. KISS.

Comment: doesn't deleting a row also triggers the macro?....can you post the error shown?

Comment: Also, `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then ' <-- run this code only if a value in column I has changed` ...You have column "B"? I might be misreading that, but how does that ensure that something in Column `I` has changed?

Comment: @SivaprasathV there's no error. Even when i remove error handling. The macro just seems to time out.

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry thats me stealing the code from an earlier code template i used. I didn't update the comment but the correct column is column B. See updated question

Comment: on deleting a row check whether the macro completes running or stopped midway. if its stopped midway the next the worksheet action wont occur as the previous macro is still running. you have to either close the workbook and open it again or stop the macro manually so that the next time worksheet change occurs it will work